Calculation of conformal dimension for Ising model in two dimensional space
Recently I was reading Ph. Di Francesco's book, "Conformal Field Theory", and in section 7.4.2 where it discussed  about Ising model, conformal dimensions $(h,\bar{h})$ are deduced from correlations in dimension two (two dimensional space with Euclidean metric).
Actually my question is about the fact that all calculations for this minimal model and computation of operator algebra, are done for radially quantized fields in 1+1 dimension (one dimensional space with periodic boundary condition and one dimension for time) but why correlation of fields are for just two dimensional space coordinate (without considering time)?
